# Obfuscate voices in VTM: Bloodlines

Tags: vampire-the-masquerade-bloodlines

What do the voices say when you use obfuscate in Vampire the Masquerade: Bloodlines?

Answer (score 3):

I cant tell you what the Voices are telling but its not a part of the original obfuscate in VTM.

I would say they(the voices) work as a sign that you still under its effect.
Its probably some pseudo-latin.

My Vampires Rulebook does not mention voices that can be heard from the vampire in obfuscate. It even makes no sense because the power effects your enviroment not the vampire itself.

[Here is a wikipage for obfuscate](http://reference.l2fury.com/index.php/Obfuscate)